# eval $(docker-machine env myvm1) does not switch to shell to talk to myvm1

Tags: linux, docker, zsh

Folks,

I'm following the Docker tutorial here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#configure-a-docker-machine-shell-to-the-swarm-manager and coming up against resistance when running this particular command:

```
eval $(docker-machine env myvm1)
```

I'm actually running (as above but with addition of sudo).

```
eval $(sudo docker-machine env myvm1)
```

I get no output from the command line to tell me anything has been done and when I run:

```
sudo docker-machine ls
```

I see that myvm1 does **not** have an active state as expected. I do know that this step isn't necessary but I'd like to understand why the command is not working and try to fix it.

I am running docker 17.09.0-ce

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

zsh shell (have tried switching to bash)

This is just on my local machine by the way, not a server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to see what's being done, run `set -x` first. (And [edit] the result of that into the question).

Comment: BTW, in general, it's better form to quote your expansions, *including* when they're going to be processed by `eval`. Thus, `eval "$(foo)"`, not `eval $(foo)`. The differences are subtle (in the `eval` case), and probably not causing your immediate bug, but when they *do* cause problems, they... well... cause problems.

Comment: Another thing that's very, **very** likely to be relevant is that `sudo` discards environment variables that aren't explicitly whitelisted. Is there a reason you're using it here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah - I have not yet given root permission to my user to not need sudo. I tried this yesterday but failed miserably.

Answer (score 9):

There's less to go wrong if you run the `eval` on the far side of `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'eval "$(docker-machine env myvm1)"; docker-machine ls'
```

Otherwise, the environment variables set by `eval`ing the output of `docker-machine env` aren't necessarily (barring some very specific `/etc/sudoers` configuration) propagated through to the future `docker-machine` invocation.

---

If you wanted to automate this with a shell function, that can be done:

```
# docker-env sudo; usage: desudo vm-name command-to-run
desudo() {
  local cmd1 cmd2
  printf -v cmd1 'eval "$(docker-machine env %q)"' "$1"; shift
  printf -v cmd2 '%q ' "$@"
  sudo bash -c "${cmd1} && exec ${cmd2}"
}
```

...used as:

```
desudo vm1 docker-machine ls
```

Comment: But that won't set any environment variables in the local environment, right?

Comment: Correct -- it sets them in the environment of the command being run by `sudo`, which is where you actually need them.

Comment: Oh I see what you're going for. This approach basically requires running this "before" every single `docker` instantiation via `sudo`.  But that shell function helps with that I suppose!

Comment: That's done it - thanks @CharlesDuffy ! I think I understand. I did actually wonder about the context of sudo and even tried prepending my eval with sudo but that didn't work. I don't spend a lot of time in the terminal, evidently. I do understand this solution and thank you all for taking the time.

Comment: Also, that script looks very useful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

**You should run `eval $(docker-machine env myvm1)`.**
In fact, you don't have to add `sudo`.

But you may doesn't have permission to run `docker` without `sudo`, here is how to solve this issue on Linux.

---

Following the steps in this article "[Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)"

1. Create the `docker` group. `sudo groupadd docker`
2. Add your user to the `docker` group. `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
4. Verify that you can run docker commands without `sudo`.`docker run hello-world`.

If you see the following error:

```
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/user/.docker/config.json -
stat /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied
```

Fix it with:

```
$ sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
$ sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R
```

Answer (score 3):

I too was having the exact same problem as posted and have spent the better part of the morning googling for an answer. I went back through the documentation and realised that I completely omitted the post-installation steps for Linux.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

I followed the instructions laid out in the section labelled **Manage Docker as a non-root user** and `eval $(sudo docker-machine env myvm1)` and the subsequent `docker-machine ls` worked as expected. In addition... it eliminates the need to prefix all your docker commands with`sudo`.

I should have RTFM I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually running (as above but with addition of sudo).

eval $(sudo docker-machine env myvm1)

I get no output from the command line to tell me anything has been done and when I run:

sudo docker-machine ls
I see that myvm1 does not have an active state as expected.

run this command it will work

sudo sh -c 'eval "$(docker-machine env myvm1)"; docker-machine ls'